# Progress bar showing wrong graphics while reusing the same layout

Tags: java, android, progress-bar

I have two different activities, both the activities are responsible for showing listviews with images. The listviews are LazyLoaders and while the images are downloaded, a progressbar is shown. Once the images show up, the progressbar disappears. Both the activities are using the same layout. I have noticed that, in case of the first activity, the progress bar shows up as expected, having a semi white color, but when the 2nd activity uses the same layout, the color of the progressbar changes, it turns into blue and look more like the gingerbread progressbar. I did not change any properties of the progressbar in the code.

The **Layout file**:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/browse_list_row_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/titleText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:paddingBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp" >

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progressBar"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:visibility="visible" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/profileImg"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"/>
        </FrameLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/browseName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="FirstName"
                android:textColor="#54575A"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

                 <TextView
                android:id="@+id/countryTxt"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Country"
                        android:textColor="#54575A"
                android:textSize="17sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/ageText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:textColor="#54575A"
                android:text=""
                android:textSize="17sp" />


        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

**The first output which is expected:**

[image: First listview using same layout and working as expected]

**The Second output which is not expected:**

[image: Second listview using same layout and showing different graphics]

**Manifest declarations:**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.test.student"
    android:versionCode="3"
    android:versionName="3.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="20" />

    <!-- Require Internet state -->

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <!-- this is for college phone number -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.test.student.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <application
        android:name="com.test.student.ParseApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="false"
        android:theme="@style/testTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.test.student.SplashScreenActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:host="http"
                    android:scheme="student" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

      <activity
            android:name="com.test.student.SearchSelection"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_search_selection"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="newActivities.FindStudentBrowseStoryActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_find_student_browse_story"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
    </application>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

</manifest>
```

**What should I do to make the second progressbar look like the first one?**

Comment: Your two activities extending from the same class? and also check your theme of activities

Comment: @Praveen  None of them uses a different theme than the default theme and the imports look similar

Comment: Can you post your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: @shhp please check manifest added in the question

Comment: Do these two activities extend different classes?

Comment: @shhp Same set of classes are extended

Comment: It is really strange!

Comment: @shhp I know. Not getting a proper solution yet